# Unable to Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE After using exclude in @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and using maven `tomcat7-maven-plugin` plugin.

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.online", "com.online.dao", "com.online.service",
        "com.online.exception", "com.online.filter", "com.online.interceptor", "com.online.validator",
        "com.online.component" }, exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootWebApplication
        extends org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

}
```

when I deploy by application by using mvn tomcat7:deploy

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:
[INFO] FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/online-web] but context failed to start
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] online-test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ......................... SUCCESS [  0.708 s]
[INFO] online-data ........................................ SUCCESS [  2.314 s]
[INFO] online-service ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.244 s]
[INFO] online-web 0.0.1 ................................... SUCCESS [ 18.471 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-19T16:37:04+05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if I remove `exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class }` application deploy successfully but there are some other issues I am facing.

Comment: Hopefully `tomcat7:deploy` has logged some more information about the failure somewhere. Perhaps somewhere in the `target` directory. Seeing the logs will make it much easier to figure out what's going wrong.